# How to append some html markup lines?

Tags: jquery, svg, append

I was wondering what the best method is to append a markup of 3/4 lines of code. So it's organized and easy to edit.

Want to append this markup to my HTML page:

```
<g class="dot previous">
<circle class="inner" cx="8.921933085501859%" cy="45" r="8"/>
<circle class="outer" cx="8.921933085501859%" cy="45" r="12"/>
</g>
```

One way is to past above code between quotes in the `append()` function, but this messed up your markup when you want to append a lot of those markups..

Look out to your advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendCircle(parent, classes, cx, cy, r) {
  var circle = $('<circle></circle>');
  circle.addClass(classes);
  circle.prop({ 'cx': cx, 'cy': cy, 'r': r });
  $(parent).append(circle);  
}

var g = $('<div></div>');
g.addClass('dot previous');

appendCircle(g, 'inner', '8.921933085501859%', '45', '8');
appendCircle(g, 'outer', '8.921933085501859%', '45', '12');

$('body').append(g);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there will be an error occur: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`. This is I think because class is not a valid value inside the function? I changed it to className and the error is disappear. Only then the circles will be added to the body without all the parameters. Any idea why? And can you also add a working example to the answer? Thank you in advance.